# Access request issue in SP 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

In my SharePoint 2013, I'm site collection administrator , I can't find the resend and withdraw button WHY?

[image]

Comment: Is this a screencap from your site collection by another user? What I'm after is that can someone else see the Resend and Withdraw options?

Comment: no , it's from internet in my situation, i can't find the two buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step to set up the access requests for your site collection, also you need to Manage invitations to external users if required for your case. 
You can take reference from - [Set up and manage access requests](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-up-and-manage-access-requests-94b26e0b-2822-49d4-929a-8455698654b3?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

**Edit:**
 -

> **Resend** and **Withdraw** options are purely dedicated to External users.
>   **Approve** and **Decline** options are dedicated to Org Users.

Please refer Screen shot:
[image]

I hope you have your answer by now! :)

Comment: thank you, i did the above steps , still not working with user in the same domain, what do you mean with external users ?

Comment: External Users are outside of your organization who doesn't have user credentials and simply treated as anonymous user. you can ignore this part if this is not the case for you.

Comment: Regrading solution: pls try adding yourself as site owner and then check : go to site settings --> Access request and Invitation --> then click on the three dots icon (...). This should be working now. I have updated my answer. pls refer.